# Map Context-Menu key to Alt Car (right)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, context-menu, keymap

I had my laptop for quite some time and just can't get used to the fact that my right alt-key is next to the context-menu key. Whenever I want to do coding special-characters, a menu pops up and has me raging. Therefore, what is the most light-weight solution to map it to Alt Car (right)?

EDIT: Using Windows 7, map in all contexts.

Comment: Welcome to SU. When you ask question about how to do X in program Y, you should say what program Y is. This question is about how to configure your operating system, so you need to say what operating system you are using.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the confusion. I'm looking to do this mapping at all times in Windows 7.

Comment: You could just try pulling the key out and removing the contact pad underneath if it bothers you that much!

Comment: SHIFT+F10 - like right click, brings up context menu. From - http://www.bilbo.com/shortcut.html  It's not about new mapping but very helpfull if you don't have win keys.

Comment: what's AltCar? you mean [AltGr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, my solution to every key-mapping problem is to download AutoHotKey and write a script to remap the key. Remapping a key is as easy as writing [Actual Key Name]::[Intended Key Use], (both of these without brackets), in NotePad, and then saving it as an .ahk. If you want to make the key ignored, replace the intended use with "return". You can figure out the Actual Key Name by looking thru the help file for the key list, or else by using a feature of the AutoHotKey program called #KeyBoardHook, which will tell you what keys were pressed recently. To use keyboard hook, just create your script, and at the top type"#InstallKeybdHook". Then while the script is running, double click on the taskbar icon, navigate to *View | "Key History and script info". Press the key that you want to know, and then refresh the list page by pressing [F5].

Hope this helps, download page below.

http://www.autohotkey.com/download/

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried a keyboard mapping product such as [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2006/07/sharpkeys_211.html) or [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/) ?

See: [Remapping the Keyboard Layout in Windows](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/remap-keyboard.htm).

Using SharpKeys, one can identify the key by pressing on it (Type Key) :

[image]